# three.js iOS lights limit?

Tags: javascript, ios, three.js, webgl

is there a limit on how many lights you can include in a three.js scene on iOS? the code below works on Linux, Mac and Windows... but does not work on iOS (tested on firefox focus and safari). if i lower the amount of lights from 15 to 14 it works fine, but when i pass 15 it doesn't work on iOS anymore

```js
let AMOUNT = 15
let scene = new THREE.Scene()
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, innerWidth/innerHeight, 0.1, 1000)
camera.position.z = 4

let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

let tx = new THREE.TextureLoader()
    .load('https://s4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/046/Purple/bd/8f/fd/mzl.emkswtfe.jpg')
let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 )
let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map:tx})
let cat = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material )
cat.position.z = -2
scene.add( cat )

// point lights

class Point {
    constructor(i){
        let g = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 0.1, 4, 4 )
        let m = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:'#ff0'})
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( g, m )
        this.light = new THREE.PointLight('#fff', 0.1, 100 )
        this.mesh.add(this.light)
        this.mesh.name = 'point'
        let y = 1 - i/8
        this.mesh.position.set(0,y,0)
    }
    update(tick){
        let x = Math.sin(tick) * 1
        this.mesh.position.x = x
    }
}

let points = []
for (let i = 0; i < AMOUNT; i++) {
    let s = new Point(i)
    points.push(s)
    scene.add(s.mesh)
}

let clock = new THREE.Clock()

function animate() {
    let tick = clock.getElapsedTime()
    requestAnimationFrame( animate )
    points.forEach(spark=>spark.update(tick))
    renderer.render( scene, camera )
}
animate()
```

```css
border { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/95/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: there is a limit, I don't know how to compute it. Shaders can only contain so many inputs. How many is up to the OS/Driver/GPU. Each light requires several inputs so when there are too many it will pass the limit. Other features require inputs as well so there's no easy answer since if you turn on other features that will mean less lights. I suggest you just experiment and record what you find and or use less lights.

Comment: thanks @gman, i also noticed that experimenting with other features ( ex: removing the texture map, or toggling on/off `renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true` as well as `mesh.receiveShadow = true` all effected what that "limit" seemed to be... trying to create something "multi-platform"... feels like iOS is really going to limit what i can do... bummer.